# Airflow: creating & passing list of tables via XCOM (without storing as a file on a drive) and setting up correct dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, task, airflow

Here's the expected flow and dependency setting that I want to achieve:

START===>Create table list(only once when DAG is triggered)===> Read & pass table names (via XCOM) ===> Create individual tasks dynamically for each table in the list===> Print table name ===>END

Here's the sample code flow:

```
start = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'start',
        dag=dag
)

end = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'end',
        dag=dag
)

#create table list:
def create_source_table_list(dsn, uid, pwd, exclude_table_list, **kwargs):
    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN={};UID={};PWD={}'.format(dsn, uid, pwd))
        cursor=cnxn.cursor()
        tables_list = []
        for row in cursor.tables():
            tables_list.append(row.table_name)
        final_list = [ele for ele in tables_list if ele not in exclude_table_list]
    return final_list

create_table_list = PythonOperator(
                task_id = 'create_table_list',
                python_callable=create_source_table_list,
                provide_context=True,
                op_args=['DSNNAME','USERID', 'PASSWORD', ['TABLE1', 'TABLE2']], 
                dag=dag
)

#function for dynamic task generation 
def createDynamicTask(task_id, callableFunction, args):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = task_id,
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable = eval(callableFunction),
        op_kwargs = args,
        xcom_push = True,
        email= ['xyz.com'],
        email_on_failure = True,
        email_on_retry = False,
        dag = dag
    )
    return task

#function to print table names
def print_tables(table_name,**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    ls = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_table_list')
    print("The table name is: ", table_name)

for table in create_source_table_list(['DSNNAME','USERID', 'PASSWORD', ['TABLE1', 'TABLE2']]):

    print_table_names=createDynamicETL('{}-dynamic_task'.format(table),'print_tables',{'table_name':str(table)})

## set dependency
start >> create_table_list
create_table_list >> [print_table_names]
print_table_names >> end
```

However, I am facing below issues/challenges/problem with above implementation:

1. Table names aren't getting stored in XCOM and want to avoid storing the table list in a file on a drive.
2. Multiple DB calls required for each table in the DB
3. Incorrect task dependency set- it only takes and shows the dependency for the last table in the list like below:
   start==> create_table_list==> {LAST_TABLE_NAME in the list}==> end

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach will very likely not work. While it's possible to dynamically create tasks, I haven't seen that you can dynamically create tasks based on xcom. The DAG Run already started when xcom will be filled, adding or removing tasks based on this sounds like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since listing tables isn't *that* computationally expensive, I'd recommend to determine that list of tables outside of the DAG. Then you can dynamically generate the required tasks.

It's a bit hacky, but if you *really* want the tables to be listed in an Airflow operator, you could consider doing the following:

- Create a separate (unscheduled) DAG with a task that updates the list of tables and stores it in an Airflow `Variable`.
- Use the `TriggerDagRunOperator` to trigger your dynamic DAG, which then contains tasks based on the contents of that `Variable`.

P.S. I'm guessing you're using MS SQL. You could use the [MsSqlOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/microsoft/mssql/operators/mssql/index.html) to query the database.